# How to stream large data from action to Response body without storing it in memory using MediaTypeFormatter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webapi, mediatypeformatter

I want my WebAPI action to return large data in chunks from the database without loading it all in memory and use a built-in JSON MediaTypeFormatter to serialize my list as a JSON object:

```
       public IHttpActionResult GetLogs(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var db = new DatabaseContext();
            var logs = db.Logs.Take(9999999).AsNoTracking();
            return Ok(logs);
        }
```

Even though I am returning an IQueryable and not loading all the data to the memory, it seems like the JSON MediaTypeFormatter loads all the data into memory instead of streaming it straight to the response body in chunks, which causes large memory consumption. How can I stream large data from my action using MediaTypeFormatters without loading all the data in memory?

Comment: The action results is calling a deserialize method.  So if deserialize waits to process entire message than you would need a deserialize methods that works with chunks.

Comment: Yes, Kirk, you are correct, thanks. @jdweng - how can I achieve that? The default JSON MediaTypeFormatter kicks in based on the request headers by default and returns the whole data instead of Transfer-Encoding: chunked response. If I start streaming the response in chunks straight from the action to the response body, then the MediaTypeFormatter doesn't kick in.

Comment: Not sure it can be done.  The Routing is based on the the class type in the action result.  So you need to get the root name in the response (the action result).  So I would think you can start looking at a custom controller deserialize method to better understand the process.